# Deleting blank line in rdd

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I'm a newbie to spark. I have an RDD which looks likes this

```
12434|arizona|2016-10-11|000
56783|california|2016-10-12|111

23456|Texas|2016-10-11|234
```

I am trying to delete the blank line between 2nd and 3rd row. I tried               `val rdd2=rdd1.filter(x=>x!='\n')`  but not working. Any suggestions how to resolve this will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
rdd1.filter(x => !x.isEmpty)
```